# CSS select next child of any tag

Tags: css, css-selectors

In CSS I can say `div > div` to get the `div` right after a `div`.
And i can say `div *` to get all elements after `div`.
But is there a way to get any element / tag directly after the given element?
Something like `div > *`. This dosnt work, but anything a long thous lines?

If you dont understand heres another example.

Code 1

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Code 2

```
<div>
  <dl>
    <dd></dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

I want a single CSS selector that will be able to get the tag right after the `div` (`ul`,`dl`).

Comment: "after" is the wrong word here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
div > *:first-child
```

Try it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JubRk/).

Comment: Im not sure why i didnt think of that. Thanks

Comment: @BoltClock - It seems your right... I have no clue what just happened. The page must have not been loading properly. With `:first-child` removed, it still works. Thanks